# Como subtrair horas de uma data sequencialmente em SQL?

Tags: sql

Tenho vários campos com `data`, `hora` e `sector`:

```
Sector|Horas|Data
------|------|-----
Corte |01:00 |12/03/2019 17:00
EXP   |00:30 |12/03/2019 17:00
Etc
```

Quero subtrair a hora da data, mas guardar sempre a anterior como mostro abaixo:

```
Sector|Horas|Data             |Resultado
------|------|-----
Corte |01:00 |12/03/2019 17:00|12/03/2019 16:00
EXP   |00:30 |12/03/2019 17:00|12/03/2019 15:30
ETC
```

Como posso resolver isso?

Comment: Como você chegou ao resultado mostrado na segunda linha? Não deveria ser 16:30?

Comment: Qual o `SGBD` que você está utilizando?

Comment: Cheguei ao resultado da segunda linha. Pk quero contar a partir do fim do outro resultado.

Comment: Neste caso a utilização de windows functions pode ajuda-lo. Consulte a documentação de seu SGBD.

Answer (score 0):

Isso depende de seu [SGBD](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sistema_de_gerenciamento_de_banco_de_dados), ou comumente chamado, *banco de dados*.

Considerando uma tabela como:

```
CREATE TABLE TABELA (
  SECTOR VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  HORAS TIME NOT NULL,
  DATA TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
);
```

### MySQL

`SELECT *, SUBTIME(DATA, HORAS) AS RESULTADO FROM TABELA;`

`SELECT *, TIMESTAMP(DATA - HORAS) AS RESULTADO FROM TABELA;`

### PostgreSQL

```
SELECT *, (DATA - HORAS) AS RESULTADO FROM TABELA;
```

### MS SQL Server

> No lugar de TIMESTAMP, usei DATETIME. <sup>[2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10262454/10707951)</sup>

`SELECT *, (DATA - CONVERT(DATETIME, HORAS)) AS RESULTADO FROM TABELA;`

`SELECT *, DATEADD(MS, DATEDIFF(MS, HORAS, '00:00:00'), DATA) AS RESULTADO FROM TABELA;` <sup>[3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28091513/10707951)</sup>